# Determine whether a predicate holds for none, some or all elements of a range

Tags: c++, algorithm

Since C++11, in the algorithms library we have [`all_of`, `any_of` and `none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) to determine whether a predicate holds on all, any or none of the elements of a range. A single call to one of these algorithms returns 1 bit of information, whereas for a particular range and predicate there are 4 possibilities:

- The predicate holds on all elements and on no elements: the range is empty;
- The predicate holds on all elements (and the range is not empty);
- The predicate holds on no elements (and the range is not empty);
- The predicate holds on some but not all elements.

Is there a concise and efficient way to find this information? Calling `all_of` followed by `none_of` is a possibility, but (a) fails to work on single-pass ranges, and (b) evaluates the predicate exactly once more than necessary. Boost would be acceptable.

Comment: I think homebrew is your only option

Comment: You can implement your own function with two calls of `find_first_of` (once with the predicate and once with its negation). Or an alternate idea: check the first manually then apply `all_of` or `none_of`.

Comment: @Csq I already made an answer with the first option - you can make one with the second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can eliminate both (a) the (b) problems if you examine the first element manually and choose between `all_of` or `none_of` depending on the result.

Code (borrowed the `enum` from @Angew):

```
enum class Result {
  empty, all, none, some
};

template <class FwIt, class Pred>
Result examine_range(FwIt from, FwIt to, Pred pred)
{
  if (from == to) return Result::empty;
  if (pred(*from)) {
    ++from;
    return all_of(from,to,pred) ? Result::all : Result::some;
  } else {
    ++from;
    return none_of(from,to,pred) ? Result::none : Result::some;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution.  From what I could see, you can even relax the requirements on `from`/`to` so that you could use an `InputIterator` rather than a `ForwardIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding this question wrongly, or is this something you could do via `std::accumulate`?

```
using eana = std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>;

template <typename T, typename FwdIt, typename Pred>
auto empty_all_none_any(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end, Pred predicate) -> eana {
  auto result = eana{begin == end, begin != end, begin != end, false};
  result = std::accumulate(begin, end, result, [&](eana& res, T& val) {
    if (predicate(val)) {
      std::get<2>(res) = false;
      std::get<3>(res) = true;
    }
    else {
      std::get<1>(res) = false;
    }
    return res;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it calculates the predicate for all elements. But, for example if the predicate value for the first of your elements are [true, false, true, ...] then you could exit after the third element saying that the predicate holds on some but not all elements.

Comment: Right, good point. This could probably be grafted onto my code, but at that point your solution becomes much more elegant (if it isn't already). By the way, is there any better way to get out of accumulate than by throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is my preferred algorithm (enum from @Angew):

```
enum class Result {
    empty, all, none, some
};
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
Result examine_range(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    bool all = true, none = true;
    for (; first != last && (all || none); ++first)
        (p(*first) ? none : all) = false;
    return all ? (none ? Result::empty : Result::all)
        : (none ? Result::none : Result::some);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the standard library functions you describe. Test both whether any elements are true, and whether any elements are false, then combine the results according to this table:

```
             any true | none true 
            ======================
 any false |  mixed   | all false |
none false | all true |  empty    |
```

Comment: That (a) fails to work on single-pass ranges, and (b) evaluates the predicate exactly once more than necessary.